# How can I compare a number delivered by bluetooth with another in mit app inventor?

Tags: android, app-inventor

[image][image][image]    I have a sensor in arduino that sending an int data by bluethooth and I need to use it in a sentence if for example

```
number delivered by bluetooth <100
do something

    #include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial miBT(11,10);
int measurePin=0;
intledPower=12;
int samplingTime =280;
int deltaTime=40;
int sleepTime =9680;
float voMeasured=0;
float calcVoltage=0;
float dustDnesity=0;
float pm05=999;
String pm05t="hola";
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(ledPower,OUTPUT);
// serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println(pm05);
miBT.begin(38400);
}
void loop(){
digitalWrite(ledPower,LOW); // power on the ED
delaymicroseconds(sampleTime);
voMeasured=analogRead(measurePin); // read the dust value
delayMicrosecond(deltaTime);
digitalWrite(ledPower,HIGH); //turn the LED off
delayMicrosecods(sleepTime);
// 0-3.3V mapped to 0-1023 integer values
//recover voltage
calcVoltage = 5*voMeasured/1024;

//Chris Nafis (c) 2012
dustDensity= 0.17 * calcVoltage-0.1;
//Ecuacion linear de PM 2.5

//Serial.print("- Voltage: ");
//SErial.print(calcVoltage);
//Serial.print("- Dust Density (mg/m3): ");
//Serial.println(dustdensity);

//SErial.print (" - PM 0.5 (particulas/0.01 ft3): ");
//Serial.println (pm05);
delay(2000)
//Serial.write(pm05);
if(miBT.avalible())
miBT.write(Serial.read()) //read arduino and send to BT
miBT.write("pm05"); //read arduino and send to BT
//miBT.read("Holad"); //read arduino and send to BT
```

this is the arduino code and i have a pic of the app here , i need to get the value of the dustdensity and  I need that if that value is greater than for example 0 and less than 300000 a circle is green, if it is greater than 300000 and less than 450000 the circle is yellow i´ll put my image here

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are getting the number?

Comment: The arduino code or the app code?

Comment: you might get more answers in the MIT App Inventor forum here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest